# too few quotes and Invalid error in stata forvalues loop

Tags: stata

I am using the following forvalues loop but it gives me error,

```
forvalues i=1/22919 {
quietly replace standarisedname="`y`i''" if schoolname=="`x`i''" & missing(standarisedname)
}
```

type mismatch (r(109)) error

But when I use compound double quotes, like

```
forvalues i=1/22919 {
quietly replace standarisedname=`"`y`i''"' if schoolname==`"`x`i''"' & missing(standarisedname)
}
```

too few quotes error is returned

and when I use,

```
forvalues i=1/22919 {
quietly replace standarisedname=""`y`i''"" if schoolname==""`x`i''"" & missing(standarisedname)
}
forvalues i=1/22919 {
quietly replace standarisedname="`"`y`i''"'" if schoolname=="`"`x`i''"'" & missing(standarisedname)
}
```

invalid 'public' error(198) is returned.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a full answer, but it is long and contains too much syntax to be a comment. It's hard to see what the real problem here is, as your example isn't reproducible.

The implication is that you have 2 x 22919 local macros named `y1` to `y22919` and `x1` to `x22919`. Correct?

A type mismatch would imply that one or both of the variables you are referring to is not string. Please show us the results of

```
describe schoolname standardisedname
```

I can't see unmatched quotes in your second example.

In your last example

```
""`y`i''""
```

and similar uses evidently don't help you. Nesting `""` doesn't usually help. Presumably `public` is part of the text of one of the local macros you are using.

I suggest you back-up and explain what you are trying to do, as my sense is that there will be an easier way to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick!
describe return the following result

                          storage        display    value
variable name     type        format     label     variable label
 schoolname      str60 %60s      
 standarisedname str42 %42s Standarised Name

Comment: So, they are both string variables. My last suggestion still stands.

Comment: I am basically replace standardi~ variable with a string stored in macro x`i' if the schoolname equal certain string stored in macro y`i'.

I have over 200,000 observation to incorporate these changes, so I am using macro to loop over these observation.

Comment: I understand what your code does. I am asking what the problem is and how and why you have created thousands of macros. (To get Stata left quotes to display properly in commands use backslash left quote.

Comment: I have raw data which was entered in excel without any data validation checks.
The problem is, majority of words have more than
50 variations (typos), which I found (for some commonly used words) and recorded those variations in the defined x macro. The actual spelling of words is defined in the macro y

Using these macros (variations), I would standardize the schoolname string variable (get rid of some defined typos) using the forvalues loop along with "subinstr" function in stata.

Since each macro is recording each typo, that is macros are thousand in numbers.
Thank you!

Comment: As that's a messy problem and you've gone down this road, it is difficult to suggest much different. It's the macros that presumably are biting somehow. As you loop over 1/22919 you could print out whatever doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you Nick! I appreciate your comments!